# NI-FI - Issue authenticating to a page to download a file

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm currently trying to get a .zip file from a webpage using nifi to do it. I am able to generate a direct download link of the file but the application needs to log in into the page before opening the direct link. I've tried using InvokeHTTP, ListWebDAV and FetchWebDAV processors and I was not able to do this properly.
I even tried to add the login and the password as attributes using the same ID used by the page(logon, temp_password). 
Also tried going for a Python code but I was not able to get any good results with it.

Every time I tried any of these methods I received a small file on the InvokeHTTP with the download link saying that authorization is required and it downloads a file that is the source code of the login page. 
Tried to look in almost everyplace on the internet without much success :/

I'm now trying to get a processor to actually log into the page and keep it that way so the invoke processor can download the zip file using the direct link.

If somebody have another idea on how I can resolve this I will be very grateful.

I can provide more info if needed, at the moment I am using the Ni-Fi 1.1.2

Thanks in advance;

Comment: Do you know what kind of auth is required? If you can download zip through browser, it will be good to catch all requests (F12 key) with headers and bodies, and then repeat them with nifi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the authentication mechanism in place by the page, you'll likely need to chain two `InvokeHTTP` processors together. Assuming the first page has a form field you fill out with the username and password, you'll make one `InvokeHTTP` which uses the `POST` method to submit the form with the provided credentials and receives a response that contains some kind of token (session ID, etc.). You will extract this value (either from a response header or the page content), and provide it to the second `InvokeHTTP` as a request header. Using your browser's Developer Tools feature as daggett suggested to observe the authentication process will allow you to determine exactly where these values are provided.